# Rmarkdown does not understand a code for table

Tags: r, datatable, r-markdown

I wanted to create a simple table in Rmarkdown :

```
| Droite | Gauche | Défaut | Centré |
|-------:|:-------|--------|:------:|
| 12 | 12 | 12 | 12 |
| 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  
Table: an exemple
```

And it just does not work with this message popping up :

```
output file: essai.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@@magyar@captionfix 

Erreur : LaTeX failed to compile essai.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See essai.log for more info.
Exécution arrêtée
```

Comment: can you share your markdown script?

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(droite=c(12,123,1),
                 gauche=c(12,123,1),
                 defaut=c(12,123,1),
                 centre=c(12,123,1))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.